# How do we get 1230 as the value when Indirect addressing mode is used?

Tags: cpu-architecture, memory-address, addressing-mode

I am trying to solve a homework problem which is as follows:

> Assume that we have the following values in the given memory
>   locations: [image: Memory value table]
>
> Also assume that the base register R1 stores 200 and is always
>   implicitly used for the indexed addressing mode. What datum is loaded
>   into the accumulator if the instruction is `LOAD 1000` for Immediate
>   addressing modes, Direct  addressing modes, Indirect addressing modes,
>   Base(Indexed) addressing modes respectively.
>
> A. 1300,1200,800,1100
>
> B. 1000,1200,800,1300
>
> C. 1000,1100,1200,800
>
> D. 1000,1300,1230,800

Given answer is D.

How do we get 1230 as the value when Indirect addressing mode is used ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo in the question.  The value at address `1300` is `1200`, not `1230`.

There's no `1230` in memory anywhere that's shown, and this is a load.  In general the final value in a register after a load is definitely a value that was in memory (possibly zero or sign-extended).  If it did any other computation it would be called something other than load.